# Is it possible to translate view path/title of custom content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm a newcomer to Drupal.

I have a Drupal installation with i18n module.

Everything works perfectly however I faced one issue.

I created custom content type and a view to display it. Now I have a quesiton... Is there any possibility to translate view path/title?

Regards,
DaveW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well known issue for all people starting their adventure with Drupal.

How to solve the problem? It's very, very simple. I presume you have your languages created and enabled - I'll use English as default language.

1. Create your view with requested title and path. I always use English language as the first language, ie. news.
2. Go to `Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases` and create new alias by clicking `Add new alias` link (if this module is disable you need to enable it).
3. From dropdown menu, select your second (or third etc.) language, in my case Polish.
4. In `Existing system path` field provide the English path of the view you created: in our case it's `news`.
5. In `Path alias` field provide your translation, ie. wiadomosci for Polish language.

Voila. Now, when Polish is the current language, it will use an alias `wiadomosci` for `news` path.

Note: Just tested on fresh latest Drupal installation - works perfectly.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me with "Path prefix" URL language detection on. Any suggestions in this case?

Comment: This works, but is there a way to also change the breadcrumb?

Comment: @EgilHansen as the answer is a bit old, I'm afraid I don't have any suggestion, sorry. I've switched from Drupal in this project since posting this answer. Sorry guys. You may consider reading Sam's answer. AFAIR it worked for path prefix as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look here:

http://reyero.net/en/drupal/drupal7_i18n_beta1_overview (This is the module author's page)

He shows options for enabling translation of taxonomy terms, which would be the path up to your actual page - such as categories you've set up for your content.

There is also a tickbox for node, which would be your content.  One would think that this would translate the either the url or the node content.

His site doesn't seem to translate to the url to spanish, but just changes menu items.  The URL falls back to the node number instead of the alias which was previously displayed.

Maybe this helps or maybe this is already obvious to you, but I would tray playing with those options.

Nice overview - http://evolvingweb.ca/story/drupal-7-multilingual-whats-new-i18n

> Path Translation
>
> The Drupal 7 Path Translation Module allows you to create translation
> sets for paths. Path translations are used for generic paths (for
> example, for views pages), not for node or taxonomy page paths. You
> can configure multilingual paths by going to Configuration » Regional
> and language » Translation sets » Paths.

Seems to imply that there is a way to translate the nodes - not sure if you have to hard code or if it will happen automatically - looks promising though.

This guide might be helpful as well:  http://drupal.org/node/133977

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seems to be to go with the Internationalisation Views module: https://drupal.org/project/i18nviews.